# SQL Server : function to calculate sum between dates with time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables with dates. First `11.12.2016 12:00:00:000` and `11.12.2016 12:45:06:000`.

I know that time between that dates is 45 minutes 06 seconds.

How to calculate and write `WHERE` statement to `SELECT` all records where time will be more than 45 minutes?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data as a table in the question.  Also tag with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATEDIFF(second,...` will be accurate up to 1 second.
With `DATEDIFF(minute,...` the error will be up to 1 minute to each direction.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM    mytable
WHERE   DATEDIFF(second,date_col_1,date_col_2) > 45*60
```

---

This is why you don't want to use datediff with `minute` to find date difference in minutes

```
declare @date1  datetime = '2016-12-01 00:00:00'
       ,@date2  datetime = '2016-12-01 00:01:59.99'

select  datediff(minute,@date1,@date2)  as datediff_minute
       ,datediff(second,@date1,@date2)  as datediff_second
```

---

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
| datediff_minute | datediff_second |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1               | 119             |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

---

```
declare @date1  datetime = '2016-12-01 00:00:59.99'
       ,@date2  datetime = '2016-12-01 00:01:00'

select  datediff(minute,@date1,@date2)  as datediff_minute
       ,datediff(second,@date1,@date2)  as datediff_second
```

---

```
+-----------------+-----------------+
| datediff_minute | datediff_second |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| 1               | 1               |
+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thank you Dudu Markovitz. Your help was grateful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `DATEDIFF` function.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute,Column1,Column2) > 45
```

You can learn more about that [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff.asp).

(Don't forget to replace`Table` `Column1` and `Column2` with the relevant names.)

Comment: Thank you user3378165. Your help was grateful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating function like this:

```
create function dbo.fn_diffdates ( @date1 datetime,  @date2 datetime)
returns bit
as begin
    declare @retValue bit = 0;
    SET @retValue = iif( datediff(minute, @date2, @date2) > 45, 1, 0)

    return @retValue
end
```

and query as below

```
select * from yourtable where dbo.fn_diffdates(date1, date2) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Kannan Kandasamy. Your help was grateful. I appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

```
select convert(varchar(50),datediff(MINUTE,   '11-12-2016 12:00:00:000', '11-12-2016 12:45:06:000' )) +' Minutes ' , convert(varchar(50),datediff(ss,   '11-12-2016 12:00:00:000', '11-12-2016 12:45:06:000' ) % 60)+ ' Seconds'
```

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow. Its better to not just post code here. Its preferred that you explain it. Also you should format it using the CODE format.